# Collapse CheckBox if ComboBox has no element selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to collapse a `CheckBox` through `Visibility` if the selected item of a `ComboBox` is `null` or empty. The source is a list of objects having two string properties: `Code` and `Name`.

I'm using a trigger binded to the `ComboBox` text.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VideoSub" SelectedItem="{Binding SubSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubsSource}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
<CheckBox Width="80" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=VideoSub, Path=IsEnabled}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=VideoSub, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more directly to use event `SelectionChanged` to control whether components are displayed.

I wrote some demo code, hope it helps:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">        
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Code"></ComboBoxItem>  
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Name"></ComboBoxItem>  
        </ComboBox>
        <CheckBox Name="MyCheckBox" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.MyComboBox.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                this.MyCheckBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                this.MyCheckBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, sometimes it's easier to use procedure (such as functions/methods) than definition (such as triggers etc) in programming :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `DataTemplate`, you should not trigger on elements inside it, but its data. If you want to hide the `CheckBox` when the `SelectedItem` is `null`, use the [`x:Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xnull-markup-extension) markup extension for comparison.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=VideoSub}" Value="{x:Null}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

As you bind `Name` to the `TextBlock`, you can add a `DataTrigger` to your style, that compares it to the [static empty string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=net-6.0). There is no need to reference the `TextBlock` itself.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=VideoSub}" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Note that you have to add an XML namespace for the `String` type.

- .NET Core: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"`
- .NET Framework: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Here the complete style that checks for `null` and emptyness.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=VideoSub}" Value="{x:Null}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </DataTrigger>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.(local:PersonModel.Name), ElementName=VideoSub}" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

By the way, you probably do not need a `DataTemplate` at all, if you just want to display a property as text in the `ComboBox`. Set the [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="VideoSub" SelectedItem="{Binding SubSelection, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubsSource}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to `SelectedItem`:

```
<CheckBox Width="80" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=VideoSub, Path=IsEnabled}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=VideoSub}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

An object itself "having two string properties: Code and Name" cannot be "empty".

There either is an item selected or there isn't.